# DB2 Convert Integer into 24 hour format

Tags: timestamp, db2

I am having an issue converting an Integer into a TIMESTAMP format in DB2.

For example, I have an integer of

> -9

[image: This is an example of my result set]

I would like to convert this integer into 24 hour format so that it reads:

> -0900

[image: This is the result that I desire.]

Thanks

Comment: This is a display issue, really.  Why are you trying to do this in SQL?  Also, not all timezones have offsets of an integer number of hours (Some places in SE Asia are -10:30), so you probably need to take that into account.

Comment: Please provide at least something in the body of this question. Just having a bunch of dots makes it confusing to figure out exactly what you want.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek I have rolled back that edit.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT TIME('00:00:00') + CAST(int6 AS DEC(6,0)) "Time" FROM (VALUES 141021) Q(int6);
```

If you put something like `141021`
The output will be like `14:10:21`

Answer (score 0):

`VARCHAR_FORMAT(100*INT(v_tz)+60*(v_tz-INT(v_tz)),'S0000')`
where
`v_tz` is the variable or column containing the time offset, this value should be a decimal, because timezones are not always exactly an hour difference, such as Newfoundland and India
The result is a VARCHAR.